# Rails Capistrano 3: Permission denied (publickey) on AWS EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy my rails (4.2) application on **Amazon ec2** through bitbucket. I have added my `id_new_rsa.pub` key in `authorized_keys` on the server. Also added same SSH keys in my bitbucket account. Added agent as well for same keys using these commands `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_new_rsa`

By using this `id_new_rsa.pub` key, I can access both the servers (root and deploy) but when I trying to deploy my application, getting below errors.

I have spent 3 days to figure out the solution but no luck yet. Please help.

[image]

**deploy.rb**

[image]

**production.rb**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, but there is missing thing. You use `publickey` slightly incorrect for the auth method. Just add the following into your :ssh_options.

```
auth_methods: ["publickey"]
```

This is working example from with EC2 and capistrano:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  user: fetch(:user),
  auth_methods: ["publickey"],
  keys: ["/path/to/key.pem"]
}
```

Make sure do give 0600 permissions to your key file.

Comment: Do you have `USER` in your server?

Comment: yes Evgeny. The 'deploy' user is in the server. I can able to login using `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` on the server and my local machine. I tried by creating new `.pem` file on EC2 -> Key Pairs and added in the ssh_option canfigurations. But still not able to connect with EC2 and bitbucket repository.